# iOS camera cpu usage

Tags: swift, avfoundation, cpu-usage, ios-camera, cvpixelbuffer

I've written my custom camera. I get a pixelBuffer from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` delegate, create MTLTexture from it and display using Metal. I've got ~ 20% CPU usage. Apple's public project [AVCamFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcamfilter_applying_filters_to_a_capture_stream?language=objc) built on the same principle have the same CPU usage.

! But `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and other AVFoundation classes like `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` have 0 CPU usage, how?

! And how can I achieve this result ?

Comment: Well, pretty obviously, if you just show the built-in capture video preview layer, you are not also getting a pixel buffer on every frame and passing it thru some sort of processing.

Comment: @matt Yes, but how Apple achieve this result?

Comment: But without any custom processing, there should be no difference between what `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` does and rendering the buffer using Metal, right?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel I don't know how works `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` under the hood. But with Metal I create MTLTexture and calculate vertices, as the result ~ 10% CPU usage.